# Does the uniform boundedness principle holds for multilinear maps as well?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, continuity

This question has been motivated by [weak* completeness of distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4615177/is-a-weak-limit-of-a-sequence-of-tempered-distributions-indeed-a-tempered-distr).

According to the answer in the above post, any barrelled locally convex topological vector space $E$ satisfies the uniform boundedness principle for its continuous dual space $E'$.

My question is

> Does the uniform boundedness principle hold for jointly continuous multilinear functionals on $E$ as well?

I have looked for any existing result on this, but it seems a bit elusive for me.

Could anyone please provide any information? I will move it to ME if this is not research-level question.

OK, I will be more specific in my question. Let $E$ be a Frechet space. Consider a sequence of jointly continuous bilinear functions $ \{T_m : E \times E \to \mathbb{C}\}$ such that the limit
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} T_m(v,w)
\end{equation}
exists for all $v,w \in E$. If we denote the limit by $T(v,w)$, then it is obviously a bilinear functional on $E$. However, my question is

> Is $T : E \times E \to \mathbb{C}$ jointly continuous as well, in analogy with [the known result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Sequences_of_continuous_linear_maps) on $F$-spaces?

I hope this clarifies my issue a bit more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand{\om}{\omega}$Let me answer your specific question.

The proof is similar to that of the uniform boundedness principle for linear functionals, but here using the identity
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    4T_m(s,t)&=T_m(x+s,y+t)-T_m(x+s,y-t) \\ 
    &-T_m(x-s,y+t)+T_m(x-s,y-t)     
\end{aligned}
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation}
for all $s,t,x,y$ in $E$.

Indeed, for natural $n$ let
\begin{equation}
    F_n:=\{(v,w)\in E\times E\colon\,\sup_m|T_m(v,w)|\le n\}. 
\end{equation}
Because the $T_m$'s are continuous, the sets $F_n$ are closed. Also, the condition
\begin{equation}
    \lim_m T_m(v,w)=T(v,w) \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation}
for all $v,w$ in $E$ implies that $\bigcup_n F_n=E$. So, by the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), for some natural $n$, some $(x,y)\in E\times E$, and some balanced neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in $E$ we have
\begin{equation}
    F_n\supseteq (x+U)\times (y+U).
\end{equation}
So, by \eqref{10}, $|T_m(s,t)|\le n$ for all $m$ and all $(s,t)\in U\times U$, and hence, in view of \eqref{20}, $|T(s,t)|\le n$ for all $(s,t)\in U\times U$.

Thus, $T$ is bounded on a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and hence continuous. $\quad\Box$

---

The same kind of argument holds for $k$-linear forms for any natural $k$. Then identity \eqref{10} will have to be replaced by the more general identity
\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
    &2^k\, T_m(s_1,\dots,s_k) &&\\ 
    &=\sum_{(\om_1,\dots,\om_k)\in\{-1,1\}^k}  
    &&(-1)^{1(\om_1=-1)+\dots+1(\om_k=-1)} \\ 
&&&\times T_m(x_1+\om_1 s_1,\dots,x_k+\om_k s_k) 
\end{alignedat}     
\tag{10a}\label{10a}
\end{equation}
for all $s_1,\dots,s_k,x_1,\dots,x_k$ in $E$. In turn, identity \eqref{10a} can be checked by writing the $k$-fold sum as a $k$-fold iterated sum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer as always. It sees evident that your proof extends to multilinear cases. Do you think my judgement is correct?

Comment: One more thing: what exactly do you mean by "a ball of radius $r>0$"? Is this radius w.r.t the metric of $E$?

Comment: @Isaac : (i) Yes, the same kind of argument holds for multilinear forms. I have added details on that. (ii) Fréchet spaces are metrizable. So, we can use balls wrt any metric metrizing the topology. However, now balls are not used.

Answer (score 4):

It follows easily from the standard case (for linear mappings) that the pointwise limit is separately continuous and a standard result states that separately continuous multi-linear mappings (say on Frechet spaces) are continuous.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the "standard result"? I vaguely remember seeing it somewhere, but sometimes it is easier for me to prove something than to find it in the literature.

Comment: Well yes, very laudable I am sure, but it is a matter of common courtesy to acknowledge priority (reference: any elementary textbook on functional analysis).

Comment: @IosifPinelis For example, Jarchow's *Locally Convex Spaces* has on page 89 Theorem 5.1.4 giving a proof for bilinear maps $E\times F\to G$ when $E$ and $F$ are metrizable tvss with one of them Baire and $G$ a general tvs.

Comment: The book does not seem like some "elementary textbook" on functional analysis to me.

Comment: @Isaac Nor is it intended to be such. Something like Rudin's FA, or at least certain parts of it should first be mastered although the specific Theorem 5.1.4 could well be included in a book like that of Rudin's FA, possibly as an exercise with some hints.

Comment: @TaQ : Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @rediscoveringamerica : (i) I did not use this "standard result" in my proof. Should I have nonetheless acknowledged it? As was noted, my proof is a simple modification of the very short and simple proof for linear functionals. Overall, I think the resulting proof is simpler and shorter than that using the "standard result" (if the proof of that result is included).

Comment: Previous comment continued: (ii) I have now searched for this "standard result" in two not quite elementary FA books and did not find it there. Even the book [recommended by TaQ](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466824/does-the-uniform-boundedness-principle-holds-for-multilinear-maps-as-well/466834#comment1211587_466873) seems to contain only the case of bilinear, rather than general multilinear forms. So, again, can you give at least one specific reference to the "standard result", for general multilinear forms?

Answer (score 3):

First, I think this is the type of questions that MO is for.

Second, Iosif Pinelis has already given an accepted answer, but for the record I give the following. "Uniform boundedness principle" and "Banach−Steinhaus" are closely related matters but some authors make a certain difference between the precise meaning of these phrases. OP's first question refers explicitly to the first without precisely specifying the meaning. The second more specific question refers to what is very close to the concept of "Banach−Steinhaus" in the sense that is used e.g. in Jarchow's *Locally Convex Spaces* on page 220. Now, the most general result in the direction of the second question, that I can "see", is the following

**Theorem.** *Let $F$ be any sequentially complete Hausdorff locally convex space, and let $E_1,\ldots\,E_k$ be any metrizable and barrelled locally convex spaces. Then the space $L$ of separately continuous multilinear maps $E_1\times\ldots\,E_k\to F$ is sequentially complete for the topology of pointwise convergence. Moreover, every vector of $L$ is in fact (jointly) continuous.*

I don't now whether there is any published proof of this, but a proof can be obtained by suitably putting together certain parts in the discussion on pages 13−22 in H. H. Keller's *Differential Calculus in Locally Convex Spaces*, Springer LNM 417, 1974. Further note for Hausdorff locally convex spaces the implications: Fréchet $\Rightarrow$ Baire $\Rightarrow$ barrelled, and that finite (and even countable) products of Fréchet spaces and barrelled spaces are of the same type, but that at least I do not know whether the same holds for "Baire". So in the case where $F$ is the scalar field (of real or complex numbers) or even a Banach space, the above theorem is only a slight generalization of the result for which Iosif Pinelis has already given a quite complete proof.

Comment: My understanding is that uniform boundness principle was established by Banach and Steinhaus and therefore carries their names. Or is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Yes, historically, according to what I know, they obtained the "uniform boundedness principle" for linear maps from a complete normed space to a normed space. However, this basic result has been generalized to varius directions and it has/these have certain rather immediate corollaries. It varies a bit from author to author by which phase one refers to each of these related results. For example, in Horváth's "famous distribution book" on page 216 the phase "Banach−Steinhaus" refers to a result similar to (but less general than) the one in Jarchow's book.

Comment: (continued) In Rudin's *Functional Analysis* (p. 43 in my copy) "Banach−Steinhaus" means a certain equicontinuity result.

Comment: I can see in p.44 of the same book that Rudin regards "Banach-Steinhaus" and "uniform boundedness principle" as interchangeable synonyms.

Comment: In my copy of Rudin's book, on page 43 he precisely writes: "... Banach−Steinhaus theorem (2.5) is often referred to as the *uniform boundedness principle*," but there is no mention that he himself would follow this convention.